# Incorrect sequence on top 3 largest value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a simple script like below

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");
    $query = "SELECT displayName,benar FROM score ORDER by benar DESC LIMIT 3";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $output[] = array(
            'displayName' => $row["displayName"],
            'benar' => $row["benar"],
            );
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    $mysqli->close();
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);    
?>
```

and from the above script requires a mysql database, the following database

```
+++displayName+++++++benar+++
+    Georgio     +    592   +
+     Mark       +    103   +
+    Daniel      +    850   +
+     Samuel     +    1100  +
+     Rudy       +    900   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

after I use my script for the above database, I get the output as below

```
[
    {
        "displayName": "Rudy",
        "benar": "900"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Daniel",
        "benar": "850"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Samuel",
        "benar": "1100"
    }
]
```

as you can see, that for the 1100 value is at the very last part, should the number 1100 should be at the top, is there any suggestion to solve this problem? thank you

Comment: what is the data type of `benar` i guess its varchar ?

Comment: ORDER BY benar + 0 - but Sam Swift's is the proper way to go.

Comment: yes, benar is varchar, do i have to change it?

Comment: @RonaldMartin - yes, to get it to come out right, you need to change it, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data type in the column to be "integer", it'll currently be some form of text at the minute, and as such reads first char onward, meaning something like the following is happening;

`9 > 8 > 1`

So changing the data type will make it read properly;

```
ALTER TABLE `score` MODIFY `benar` INT;
```

See here for help;
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html